# Database trigger, retrieving data from other nodes. Firebase Cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

i have a function that will trigger when the 'location' is updated under 'users'. I want to be able to iterate through all the 'users' and be able to compare their 'location's.

Right now when i console.log `event.data.val()` i just get the 'location' data.
How do i go up a level and see the other 'users'

```
exports.getNearest = functions.database.ref('/users/{pushId}/location').onWrite(event =>{

console.log(event.data.val());
return;
}
);
```

my database is structured like this:

https://gyazo.com/9d7a4ddba2cd311b21d78d7622b59c36

Answer (score 0):

[event.data.ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#ref) is a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference) where your function triggered.  This means event.data.ref.[parent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#parent) is a reference to the parent node of that location. You can reach the root of your database using event.data.ref.[root](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#root).  If you need full read and write access regardless of the user who invoked the function, you may also want to use event.[adminRef](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#adminRef) instead of ref.